# pip3 update to (20.3.3), does not reflect under the pip3 -V 20.0.2

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, python, pip

Running Ubuntu 20.04

I need to upgrade pip3 to the latest version 20.3.3.  I followed instructions on how to upgrade, and it looked like it worked.  However, when I type in pip3 -V , the result is 20.0.2.  How do I make it so the pip -V command reflects the 20.3.3 version instead of the 20.0.2 version?

**pip3 Update Commands:**

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/1e/d91d7aae44d00cd5001957a1473e4e4b7d1d0f072d1af7c34b5899c9ccdf/pip-20.3.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pip-20.3.3.tar.gz    
cd pip-20.3.3
sudo python3 setup.py install 


Installed
   /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-20.3.3-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for pip==20.3.3
Finished processing dependencies for **pip==20.3.3**
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/Desktop/pip-20.3.3$
```

**pip3 -V command to verify version**

```
pip3 -V
pip **20.0.2** from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Thank you!

Comment: The new pip3 probably got installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thank you  Nmath, this is new to me.  I'll check the /usr/local/bin

Comment: For some odd but good reason, it's working! 

parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ pip3 -V
pip 20.3.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)